# Extract specific data from json object and store them in a list

Tags: java, json, groovy, devops, bitbucket-api

I´m new to the world of json format. I have Json info stored in a json object and I only want to extract name key values in a list. At least I have one user and sometimes more than one user. Extraction using Java or Groovy.

```
{
  "reviewers": [
    {
      "user": {
        "name": "name1.n1",
        "emailAddress": "example@example.com"
      },
      "role": "REVIEWER"
    },
    {
      "user": {
        "name": "name2.n2",
        "emailAddress": "example2@example.com"
      },
      "role": "REVIEWER"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

basic groovy+json doc here: https://groovy-lang.org/json.html

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def json = '''{
  "reviewers": [
    {
      "user": {
        "name": "name1.n1",
        "emailAddress": "example@example.com"
      },
      "role": "REVIEWER"
    },
    {
      "user": {
        "name": "name2.n2",
        "emailAddress": "example2@example.com"
      },
      "role": "REVIEWER"
    }
  ]
}
'''

def obj = new JsonSlurper().parseText(json)

println obj.reviewers.collect{ it.user.name } // v1
println obj.reviewers*.user.name              // the same as above but shorter
```

Comment: Is this println obj.reviewers*.user.name going to iterate over all user and names ? if yes is it possible to store them in a list of string ?

Comment: yes. it will iterate all elements in array. it's a 'spread operator'. read here: http://groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_spread_operator

Comment: Great answer MAN. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Using Java with library org.json.JSONObject;

```
   JSONObject json =new JSONObject(YOUR_JSON_HERE );        
            JSONArray array = json.getJSONArray("reviewers" );
            for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++){
                JSONObject user =array.getJSONObject(i);   
                System.out.println(user.getJSONObject("user").get("name"));
            }
            
    
        }
```

Comment: How can you access length() using array object ?

Comment: No,array is  JSONArray array = json.getJSONArray("reviewers" ); not jsonObject

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of names like this, using just Groovy:

```
jason = '''{
  "reviewers": [
    {
      "user": {
        "name": "name1.n1",
        "emailAddress": "example@example.com"
      },
      "role": "REVIEWER"
    },
    {
      "user": {
        "name": "name2.n2",
        "emailAddress": "example2@example.com"
      },
      "role": "REVIEWER"
    }
  ]
}
'''


import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def jsonslurper = new JsonSlurper()
def object = jsonslurper.parseText(jason)

List names = object.findAll { it.value instanceof List }
    .values()
    .flatten()
    .collect { it.user.name }

println names
```

Comment: .values() method is not accessible also I can´t find it in the official doc http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html. Is findAll{} is going to iterate over all element ?

Comment: It iterates over values that are lists, i.e. that have more than one occurences, like user. `.values()` returns a collection of the values contained in the returned map. It is in the 5th example [here](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/documentation/#_for_in_loop) in the official documentation.